# Building a yocto image for RPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto

Recently I started with yocto-project to build images for raspberry-pi.
I cloned poky and meta-raspberrypi under a directory named as yocto_project on my ubuntu host. Initiated the build using `source oe-init-build-env rpi-build`.
The first image I created the rpi-basic-image which was a successful attempt.

Upon booting RPi with the image I got a CLI based interface, but the problem is few commands are missing. Came to know by-default all the packages didn't get combine with image, we need to add it manually for example systemd.

If I run `bitbake-layers show-recipes` I get long list of all the recipes available for RPi. So I added the text `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " systemd"` after reading some documents online to append systemd. After this when I `bitbake rpi-basic-image` got error as `ERROR: Nothing RPOVIDES 'systemd' (but /path_to/rpi-basic-image.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: systemd was skipped: 'systemd' not in DISTRO_FEATURES
ERROR: Required build target 'rpi-basic-image' has no buildable providers`

Don't have clue, why I get this error. How to resolve it. Also do I have to manually add those packages/recipes using build/local.conf to get all the commands. 
Need a good explanation/guidance .

Answer (score 1):

From [Selecting an Initialization Manager - Yocto Development Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#selecting-an-initialization-manager):

```
 DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
 VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
```

You can set those variables in your `local.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't gave error. Undergoing the build process now.

Comment: Also matter the line `DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"` from the link if there is still sysvinit present in some extent.

Comment: You can also add the line  `VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""`, it will remove files in /etc/init.d.

Comment: Also when i want to add a custom recipe, let say a helloworld recipe, so do I have to `bitbake helloworld.bb` first and then append that package to Rpi before I do `bitbake rpi-basic-image` or I have to add the package name in the .conf file and `bitbake rpi-basic-image`

Comment: @user7345878  In this case you need `IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "helloworld"`

Comment: you mean to say in `build/.conf` file and there is no need to bake the recipe separately ?

Comment: You can set this option in `local.conf` file and its builded automatically. You can bake it manually for testing but if its in your layers or in your local.conf its interally build automatically

Comment: Thanks man, you resolved my issue. Previously I was putting it into bblayer.conf, that was the mistake.

Comment: Yes. Is there any other manual or tutorial apart form the link you posted above to have a good hold with yocto?

Comment: @user7345878 There is the general Yocto documentation: https://www.yoctoproject.org/documentation , but regarding writing recipes I consider this link a nice reference: https://a4z.bitbucket.io/docs/BitBake/guide.html